# Serving a Tomcat app at the root of Nginx

Tags: tomcat, nginx

I have Nginx sitting in front of my Tomcat server.  I can access my app just fine by going to http://myhost.example.com/myapp, but I would ideally like to just browse to http://myhost.example.com without adding the /myapp to the URL.  I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Here is my Nginx config for Tomcat.

```
upstream stats {
  ip_hash;
  server localhost:8080;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name myhost.example.com;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/stats.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/stats.error.log debug;

  gzip on;
  gzip_min_length 1000;
  gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
  gzip_types text/css text/html text/plain application/javascript application/xml application/json application/x-font-woff images/png;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarder-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://stats;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }

  location ~ ^/(images|styles|scripts|views) { 
    root /srv/tomcat/webapps/stats/public;
    log_not_found off;
  }
}
```

Comment: I see no `myapp` in config so you should configure your tomcat to serve application from root

Comment: Having Tomcat serve from root isn't desirable.  I managed to get it working though just now, by changing "proxy_pass http://stats" to "proxy_pass http://stats/myapp".